# Relative file paths for links within a PHP include

Tags: php, html

I have a header.php file that I'm using as an include on every page of my website. Within it are the site's navigation links.

**Note**: I don't want to use absolute file paths as I have no idea of the folder structure of the server on which the site is going to be uploaded. It needs to work no matter where the website is placed on the server. With that in mind I have two questions:

**1**) Is there some PHP I can apply to the beginning of the file path whenever I include the header.php? My website will have many sub-directories and it will simply be too time-consuming mentally traversing the site to point to the folder that it resides in each time I want to include it.

**2**) How can I ensure that the navigation links within header.php are always correct? e.g. a link back to the home page would be '../index.php' if it's one directory below, but anywhere else it wouldn't work.

I would greatly appreciate help, thanks.

Comment: Are all the site's files under the document root?

Comment: We solved a similar issue using an autoloader to call a class that would be used in multiple scripts, some in different subdirectories. Try putting your header.php script into a class and then calling an autoloader, it simplifies your project a lot and you don't need to have 30 requires in each script to load all your dependencies

Comment: @AdamForbis Yes, but the document root will be different once it's on the server. So I can't use something like $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

Answer (score 1):

First make a php file that will contain your paths (name it for example ini.php and put it in folder ini):

```
defined("YOUR_BASE_PATH")
    or define("YOUR_BASE_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'));
```

Then in your header.php do the following (include ini file that contains your path defines):

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/ini/ini.php");
include_once(YOUR_BASE_PATH  . "/nocache.php");
```

And now you easily use paths within your project without hassle!
Fairly good solution and you can move the folder as you like, as long as you update the ini file!

Now that you have set it up like this, you can change all your links to use the actual path:

```
<a href="<?php echo PathToUrl(YOUR_BASE_PATH . "/index.php"); ?>">test link</a>
```

Make a simple function in your header.php for PathToUrl:

```
function PathToUrl($path)
{
    $path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $path)
    return $path;
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: The solution proposed works for any amount of subfolders. You just have to specify one file within your folder structure that specifies the other paths you may use.

Comment: The use of (dirname(__FILE__) causes a 'Not allowed to load local resource' error message' in Chrome's console.

Answer (score 0):

use the magic constant `__DIR__`...

From PHP's documentation:

> **DIR**   The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory.

then use it like this:

$file = **DIR** . "/../somefile.txt";

also, in header.php (or any other script that is *always* loaded first, you can set a constant:

```
const PROJECT_DIR = __DIR__ . "/..";
```

and then always refer to `PROJECT_DIR`

## 2

This one is tricky :/ I don't think it's possible, and it also sounds very unsecure (if you can access all files on the server by just adding a bunch of `..`s, for example: `../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Good luck!

Comment: How are they supposed to gain access to the `PROJECT_DIR` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using PHP magic constants. Try the following:

```
__DIR__
```

Add that to your include links prior to the start of the string... Example:

`require __DIR__ . "/file_name.php";`

You can read more about it here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: `__DIR__`: The directory of the file. So how do they get to header.php from any location inside their directory? Nested subdirectory for example? If they use your script inside `dir`, the `__DIR__` variable will be `dir`, if it's used inside `dir/subdir` then `__DIR__` will be `dir/subdir`.